# Optimize this JS function to avoid Forced reflow

Tags: javascript

there is a code snippet. DevTools marks 4 tasks (Recalculate style + Layout) as Long tasks with Forced reflows. They refer to this code snippet:

```
e(function() {
        var t = document.body
          , i = t.appendChild(i = document.createElement("div"));
        i.offsetHeight,
        e.extend(i.style, {
            minHeight: "100px",
            height: "auto",
            padding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0
        }),
        e.support.minHeight = 100 === i.offsetHeight,
        e.support.selectstart = "onselectstart"in i,
        t.removeChild(i).style.display = "none"
    }),
```

I have 2 questions:

1. what does this code actually do?
2. how to optimize it to not have the reflows?

---

Here is what I have regarding the 1st question:

The given JavaScript function is creating a new *div* element and appending it to the body of the HTML document. Then, it is setting various styles for the newly created *div* element and testing if the styles are supported by the browser. Specifically, it sets the minimum height of the *div* element to 100px, sets the height to "auto", sets padding and border width to 0, and tests if the minimum height of 100px is supported by checking the *offsetHeight* property of the div element. In short, there are manipulations with the DOM, which cause the Forced reflows.

The forced reflow is happening because of the style changes made to the newly created element "i". Whenever the styles of an element are updated, the browser recalculates the layout of the entire page and then repaints it, which is known as a forced reflow. In this case, when the "minHeight" property is set to "100px", the browser has to recalculate the layout, as the height of the element has changed. Then, when the "height" property is set to "auto", the layout is recalculated again, which is why a forced reflow is triggered.

It is generally considered best practice to minimize forced reflows, as they can significantly impact the performance of your website or web application. One way to minimize forced reflows is to batch style updates, so that multiple changes can be made to the elements in a single layout recalculation and repaint.

---

What I have regarding the 2nd question:

To optimize the code and minimize forced reflows, you could batch the style updates into a single update by modifying the style properties before appending the element to the body. Here's an example:

```
e(function() {
    var i = document.createElement("div");
 
    e.extend(i.style, {
      minHeight: "100px",
      height: "auto",
      padding: 0,
      borderWidth: 0,
      display: "none"
    });
 
    var t = document.body.appendChild(i);
    i.offsetHeight;
 
    e.support.minHeight = 100 === i.offsetHeight;
    e.support.selectstart = "onselectstart" in i;
  });
```

By making all of the style updates before the element is added to the body, you can minimize the number of forced reflows that occur. The layout of the page will only be recalculated once, when the element is added, rather than after each individual style update.

Are the answers correct? I am bad at JS and I doubt. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure the `i.offsetHeight;` on its own serves any actual purpose here.

Comment: `appendChild` returns the appended element. So `t` and `i` are the same thing. Also not sure what you expect `e.support.minHeight = 100 === i.offsetHeight` to do. Is `minHeight` a boolean property?

Comment: Couldn't this have been the *not* minified code of the function?